# Does code duplicate detection work for TypeScript language in SonarQube?

Tags: typescript, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube version 5.6.  Using TypeScript plugin from https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin. Code coverage and Code Smells are working but not duplicates though.  Based on the following log, it seems like it is not supported. Does anyone know of a way to check for duplicates in TypeScript code?

Here's the relevant section from the batch job:

10:52:15 INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (wrapped)
10:52:15 INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for ts
**10:52:15 DEBUG: No CpdMapping for language ts**
10:52:15 INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (wrapped) (done) | time=0ms
10:52:15 INFO: Calculating CPD for 0 files
10:52:15 INFO: CPD calculation finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to a non-Sonar solution, I found https://github.com/kucherenko/jscpd to work well. Here is an example output:

```bash
jscpd --pattern=**/*.ts src/
```

Produced:

```
Clone found (typescript):
 - src/file1.ts [146:12 - 153:6] (7 lines, 93 tokens)
   src/file2.ts [122:2 - 130:6]

...lots of lines like that...

┌────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ Format     │ Files analyzed │ Total lines │ Total tokens │ Clones found │ Duplicated lines │ Duplicated tokens │
├────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ typescript │ 299            │ 12781       │ 95718        │ 40           │ 685 (5.36%)      │ 5318 (5.56%)      │
├────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Total:     │ 299            │ 12781       │ 95718        │ 40           │ 685 (5.36%)      │ 5318 (5.56%)      │
└────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┘
Found 40 clones.
Detection time:: 1.286s
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use SonarTS, official plugin developed by SonarSource https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarts